# how to pass password to a command in bash

Tags: bash, passwords

I want to write a bash script that will execute one command in the script, and the command need read some thing as password. So how can I pass the password to the command in the script?

```
$ota_gen -k $ota_key -i $1 -p $ota_tools $2 $ota_out_file
```

ota_key is a private key that need to be visited with a password, so how can I do it?
thank you.

ps: thanks  hlovdal for help.
expect maybe what can help. But I don't know if it can interact with bash script, such as how to pass parameters from script to expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quite common tool for feeding programs with proper input (like for instance passwords) non-interactively is the tool [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). The following example is given on the wikipedia page:

```
# Assume $remote_server, $my_user_id, $my_password, and $my_command were read in earlier 
# in the script.
# Open a telnet session to a remote server, and wait for a username prompt.
spawn telnet $remote_server
expect "username:"
# Send the username, and then wait for a password prompt.
send "$my_user_id\r"
expect "password:"
# Send the password, and then wait for a shell prompt.
send "$my_password\r"
expect "%"
# Send the prebuilt command, and then wait for another shell prompt.
send "$my_command\r"
expect "%"
# Capture the results of the command into a variable. This can be displayed, or written to disk.
set results $expect_out(buffer)
# Exit the telnet session, and wait for a special end-of-file character.
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: or even autoexpect to create expect script

Comment: I have a try, and there is a error, spawn not found.So could it be used in bash script? my file begin with #!/bin/bash

Answer (score 1):

OK, I google and get the answer of how to interact with expect in bash script.
I have added lines bellow in my script.Ant it tack effect.

th

```
    EXEC=$(expect -c "
spawn $ota_gen -k $ota_key -i $1 -p $ota_tools $2 $ota_out_file
expect \"Enter password for .... key>\"
send \"$PASSWD\r\"
interact
")
    echo $EXEC
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing sensitive information around and use it regularly you are probably best encrypting it.

Putting something like

```
#create key as follows - will prompt for password
#echo -n 'secret you want encrypted' | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc  -a -salt -pbkdf2|base64
export MY_SECRET='VTJGc2RHVmtYMTlzVnBGWXNYUitLWlpYT3BWdStaQXJXeUVwc1JORnFsNWswZXJKT1dkRWpsWkxLWVFnK1hONQo='
```

Into your .bashrc will give you an encrypted environment variable that you can access where ever you need a secret, and you will be prompted for you passphrase/password that you used when creating the environment variable.

In the example above it is 'secret'

You access it is a command as follows

```
`echo $MY_SECRET|base64 --decode|openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -d -salt -pbkdf2 `
```

e.g.

```
xfreerpd /parameters.... /p:`echo $MY_SECRET|base64 --decode|openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -d -salt -pbkdf2`
```

For your query where $ota_key is the secret

```
$ota_gen -k $ota_key -i $1 -p $ota_tools $2 $ota_out_file
```

You can create the variable as follows

```
ota_key=`echo -n 'secret you want encrypted' | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc  -a -salt -pbkdf2|base64`
```

Then use it as follows

```
$ota_gen -k `echo $ota_key|base64 --decode|openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -d -salt -pbkdf2 ` -i $1 -p $ota_tools $2 $ota_out_file
```

openssh will prompt you for a password to encrypt and decrypt each time, you can supply one as part of the command, but then you are just hiding things from the history etc.  Have a look at https://www.tecmint.com/generate-encrypt-decrypt-random-passwords-in-linux/ for some info on using openssh for this. https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-base64-encode-and-decode-from-command-line/ for base64 and [How to assign an output to a shellscript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072351/how-to-assign-an-output-to-a-shellscript-variable) for different options on command substitution I have used back-tick ` above

PS Adding a function like

```
get-key()
{
 echo -n "$1"|base64 --decode|openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -d -salt -pbkdf2
}
```

To your bashrc gives you quick access to the secret if you need it