# How to assign an output to a shellscript variable?

Tags: shell, pipe, bc

How to assign this result to a shell variable?

Input:

`echo '1+1' | bc -l`

Output:

`2`

**Attempts**:

(didn't work)

```
#!bin/sh
a=echo '1+1' | bc -l
echo $a
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a BASH variable equal to the output from a command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-bash-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You're looking for the shell feature called command-substitution.

There are 2 forms of cmd substitution

1. Original, back to the stone-age, but completely portable and available in all Unix-like shells (well almost all).

   You enclose your value generating commands inside of the back-ticks characters, i.e.

   ```
   $ a=`echo 1+1 | bc -l`
   $ echo $a
   2
   $
   ```
2. Modern, less clunky looking, easily nestable cmd-substitution supplied with `$( cmd )`, i.e.

   ```
   $ a=$(echo 1+1 |  bc -l)
   $ echo $a
   2
   $
   ```

Your 'she-bang' line says, `#!/bin/sh`, so if you're running on a real Unix platform, then it's likely your `/bin/sh` is the original Bourne shell, and will require that you use option 1 above.

If you try option 2 while still using `#!/bin/sh` and it works, then you have modern shell. Try typing `echo ${.sh.version}` or `/bin/sh -c --version` and see if you get any useful information. If you get a version number, then you'll want to learn about the extra features that newer shells contain.

Speaking of newer features, if you are really using bash, zsh, ksh93+, then you can rewrite your sample code as

```
a=$(( 1+1 ))
```

Or if you're doing more math operations, that would all stay inside the scope, you can use shell feature arithmetic like:

```
(( b=1+1 ))
echo $b
2
```

In either case, you can avoid extra process creation, but you can't do floating point arithmetic in the shell (whereas you can with `bc`).